# Adobe/Apache Flex: Deselect all items in bar chart

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a BarChart in my Flex application. It is displaying a BarSeries. If I want to disable all items except one, I can simply use the selectedIndex or selectedItem properties of the series.

Now I want to disable all chart items. How can I do this?

selectedIndex = -1 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use clearSelection() to unhighlight all chart items